# NULL check in WHEN statement is not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I expect 'No Conversion' should be printed for the below code but instead receiving the following error 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.'
When the `TRY_PARSE` inside the `WHEN` statement returns null then the `THEN` block should execute?

```
DECLARE @VALUE varchar(20) = 'NA'

SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN TRY_PARSE(@VALUE AS DECIMAL) IS NULL
          THEN 'No Conversion'
          ELSE (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 3), @VALUE, 0))
    END
```

Comment: It's not the `NULL` check that's failing, it's that you're truly Ng to return either a `varchar` or `decimal` in the same expression. You can't do that, as an expression can only return one data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All branches of a `CASE` expression need to have the same type.  Given that the error message is text, you should also be including the cast decimal value as text, something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_PARSE(@VALUE AS DECIMAL) IS NULL
            THEN 'No Conversion'
            ELSE CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(decimal(10,3), @VALUE, 0)) END
```